# Select value from row to use in calculation

Tags: r

I am trying to select the value from a row where a column has a particular value so I can use it in a calculation. i have tried to use dput but it appears not to work -- at least using the instructions on stackoverflow for producing a reproducible example.

```
 total.history <- sum(recommendation$Spent[recommendation$Account=="History"])
```

```
$ Account: chr  "Art" "Biology" "Botany" "Languages" ...
     $ Product: chr  "Humanities" "Science" "Science" "Humanities" ...
     $ Region : chr  "Art" "Biology" "Botany" "Languages" ...
     $ Revenue: int  2000 75 1000 1000 200 200 5000 100 100 200
     $ Spent  : int  1000 30 444 234 100 123 250 56 23 156
     $ Left   : int  1000 45 556 766 100 77 4750 44 77 44
```

Comment: It's difficult to infer some things. For instance, assuming that `recommendation` is a frame as in the end of your code block, then `recommendation[,5]` would be `recommendation$Spent`, which is not `character` ... and `recommendation[,5]=="History"` is obviously not what you're doing. Also, you have `summarise(total.revenue-spent.account)` which is not assigning to a name ... which is fine, I guess, but it is producing a column named `"total.revenue - spent.account"` which is both uncommon and not used anywhere, is it relevant to your question? Can you add your expected output?

Answer (score 1):

We can do

```
with(recommendation, sum(Revenue[Account == "Biology"]))
#[1] 75
```

If there are more than one element, use `%in%` (or add `|` with another expression)

```
with(recommendation, sum(Revenue[Account %in% c("Biology", "Botany")]))
#[1] 1075
```